# Send Character TO CONIN$ (Windows Console)

Tags: c++, windows, console

If you want to spawn a Windows console in an otherwise SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS application you can use this code:

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
    FILE* file = nullptr;
    _wfreopen_s(&file, L"CONIN$", L"r", stdin);
    _wfreopen_s(&file, L"CONOUT$", L"w", stdout);
    _wfreopen_s(&file, L"CONOUT$", L"w", stderr);
}
```

The _wfreopen_s function maps stdin to CONIN$ and provides a pointer to pointer in the file variable (which we are effectively discarding).

What I'd like to do is instead map an input from something other than stdin, for example, another file stream and then write that stream to CONIN$.

For a larger picture of what I'm trying to do here, I've got a secondary thread running std::getline(std::cin... which blocks. I'd like the thread context object to just send a \n to the console to break the blocking call.

If there are other ideas, I'm open. The alternative currently is that I print a message to the console that says "Shutting down, press ENTER to quit..." Which, I guess, also works ;)

What I tried was using the `FILE* conin = new FILE();` and then did a memcpy to fill it with a \n and then I used WriteFile to that pointer, thinking that it might write the file stream out to CONIN$, and while the code compiles, and the contents of the FILE* appears to be correct (0x0a), it does not appear to send that stream to the console.

I tested this by having `std::cout` above and below the code testing the stream write. If it works, I'd expect the two lines to be on separate lines, but they always show up on the same, suggesting that I'm not sending the file stream.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You should not discard the `FILE*` handle, otherwise you won't be able to manipulate it, in particular you won't be able to properly flush/close it if required.

If you're working with **threads**, simply give the `FILE*` to the thread that requires it. Threads share the same memory space.

If you're working with **processes**, then you should create a pipe between the two processes involved (see Win32 API for [CreatePipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe) for details), and connect one's `stdout` to the other's `stdin`.